# call data from service in controller using angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, json, service

Hi Friends I am new in angular and figuring out that how to call data from service to controller. Please check my code below

**data.json**

```
[{
    "brandname" : "VU",
    "image" : "images/1.jpeg",
    "detail" : "Vu 102cm (40) Full HD LED TV",
    "price": "20,000",
    "productId" : "001"

},{
    "brandname" : "Micromax",
    "image" : "images/52.jpeg",
    "detail" : "Micromax 81cm (31.5) HD Ready LED",
    "price": "12,489",
    "productId" : "052"

}]
```

**contoller.js**

```
var appProduct = angular.module('assignment', []);

appProduct.service('productlist', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $http({method : 'GET',url : 'js/data.json'})
            .success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.items = data;
                //console.log(data)
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                alert("Error");
            });
        setTimeout(function(){
          $scope.$apply();
        },1);
}])



appProduct.controller('productGrid', function($scope, $http, productlist){

  $scope.item = productlist.items;
  console.log(productlist.items)

})
```

Above mention code giving me error in console `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- productlist`. Please help my guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inject `$scope` to service, because it can be bound only to controller. `$scope.$apply()` should be called from the controller when the service finishes its job.

Additionally - get rid of "success" and "error" methods, [they're deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Your code should looks like below:

```
var appProduct = angular.module('assignment', []);

appProduct.service('productlist', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getProducts: function() {
            return $http.get('js/data.json')
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function() {
                    return "Error while fetching data";
                });
        }
    }
}]);



appProduct.controller('productGrid', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', 'productlist', function($scope, $http, $timeout, productlist) {
    productlist.getProducts().then(function(data) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

Here is the Plunker of this working: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/i3XGwbQLQAfzT2jA7ebZ?p=preview)

Service is returning a promise from `$http` call. Then, in controller, we can resolve the data and manipulate with the scope.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i still getting error `Error: $http is not defined` after using your code... please chck

Comment: @Kamal, oh, my bad, I forgot to inject `$http` to service. I've fixed the code.

Comment: ok.. but now I'm getting `productlist is not a function` in console :(

Comment: @Kamal, ok, last modification, should be fine now. I thought I can directly call the service if there is only one method, apparently I can't ;).

Comment: @itichi I really appreciate your help.. but your code yet nt working still getting below error `angular.js:13642 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at angular.js:68
    at beginPhase (angular.js:17738)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17476)
    at controller.js:103
    at processQueue (angular.js:16104)
    at angular.js:16120
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17191)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17486)
    at done (angular.js:11637)`

Comment: @Kamal, strange, it was working on my Plunker. I have added a `$timeout` instead of `$scope.$apply()` because `$timeout` does the same at the end of the digest. I have attached a working example on Plunker. Actually it should work event without `$timeout` and `$apply`.

Comment: i think you don't need $scope.$apply() nethier $timeout you already use $http service and then assign to $scope after then ... try it without $scope.$apply()  it should work

Answer (score 0):

@Kamal,You need to inject $http in your service.
Could you remove $scope from your service..
Make sure dependency is defined and will fix the problem